# Update jekyll site

Tags: ruby, bash, web, jekyll, rbenv

I'm trying to update a jekyll blog and wanted to view it on my browser first. I ran `jekyll serve` and got:

```
rbenv: jekyll: command not found

The `jekyll' command exists in these Ruby versions:
2.1.0
```

Why do I get this error? I also ran `bundle exec jekyll serve`:

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

If it helps, this is the result of `echo $PATH`

> /Users/BLAH/.rbenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/aa/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin

If this helps also, this is the result of `rbenv versions`

```
  system
  1.9.3-p551
  2.0.0-p353
  2.0.0-p598
  2.1.0
  * 2.1.4 (set by /Users/BLAH/.rbenv/version)
```

How do I make `jekyll serve` work again?

Comment: @xlembouras, hey, thanks for your answer. If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it as it was the first one.

Comment: no neeed for that @user27307254534534534543675765 accept Jordan's answer which is complete and correct.

Comment: @xlembouras, ok. thank you for being generous. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You installed the Jekyll gem when you were using Ruby 2.1.0, but then you switched to 2.1.4, which doesn't have Jekyll in its gemset.

You either need to install Jekyll in the gemset you're using with `gem install jekyll`, or you need to switch to the other Ruby with `rbenv local 2.1.0`.

Comment: @Jordon, hey, thanks for the explanation. I'm accepting the comment by xlembouras as the answer if it's turned into one as it was the first one. I really do appreciate the explanation though.

Answer (score 3):

> I also ran `bundle exec jekyll serve`
>   This is the result:
>   Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

You need to start the server. I solved the problem with:

```
$ jekyll serve
# => A development server will run at http://localhost:4000/
# Auto-regeneration: enabled. Use `--no-watch` to disable.

$ jekyll serve --detach
# => Same as `jekyll serve` but will detach from the current terminal.
#    If you need to kill the server, you can `kill -9 1234` where "1234" is the PID.
#    If you cannot find the PID, then do, `ps aux | grep jekyll` and kill the instance.
```